# How to get around error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError in Google reCaptcha v2?

Tags: recaptcha

After clicking on the checkbox and selecting all the pictures in the popup, the checkbox is marked with a green arrow and that's it. Nothing goes anywhere, and the console displays Uncaught (in promise) TypeError. Before this it worked all day and then suddenly stopped.

Comment: can you show me your code?

Comment: I also stumbled upon this issue. The irony is that the reCAPTCHA works on a page and on other pages it does not. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: I found the issue in my case.

Working on a old WordPress project, the implementation of the jQuery library was all messed up.

In some placed, the shorthand `$` for jQuery worked and in others, it didn't. So when I implemented the reCAPTCHA on some older pages it seems that it couldn't recognize `$` as jQuery and threw `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError` in the console.